# How can I change the order of extended displays?

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

I have a laptop with external monitor, with option: "Extend these displays".
I have my laptop on the left, physically.
Therefore I would like to drag windows from big monitor to the left.
However, in "Multiple display settings" my laptop screen appears on the right side.
How can I change the order so, that my laptop screen would be first?

UPDATE: OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right click your desktop and select **Screen resolution**.

[image: Desktop context menu]

Drag the screen images to the position you want (the images with numbers on them) and then click **Apply**.

[image: Drag to change display order]

Comment: Similar technique worked on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

You can click and drag and drop the monitors in the display settings screen.

Here is a [quick video](http://www.screencast.com/t/JRA1j514u) showing how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation with three monitors. I am using windows 8.1. My laptop had glare due to the lighting condition at my workplace so I wanted to switch to two additional screens.

Not only I wanted to change the order of the monitors but also I wanted to change the primary display device.

Thus, in addition to drag and drop option, there is also an option for defining the 'main display'. The advantage is that, it can let you switch the primary display from your laptop to external monitors.

All you have to do is set the monitors in the required sequence. Click on the monitor you want to set as your primary display and then SELECT the option:'Make this my main display'

[External monitor defined as primary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYRpv.png)

For me, once I made this change, I did not have to re-do again; even when laptop was taken off. This makes the things bit easier.